# Is there an equivalent of Apache's auto_prepend_file in IIS 6.0

Tags: php, iis, iis-6

On a LAMP stack I was able to use:

```
> php_value auto_prepend_file bootstrap.php
```

in .htaccess to bootstrap a bunch of commands that I wanted to execute before any page was ever processed.

Is it possible to do the same in IIS 6.0 ?

UPDATE:
Not the prettiest solution, but since I have one site on this server I just added the auto_prepend_file setting in php.ini and restarted IIS

Comment: auto_prepend_file with PHP has always struck me as a nasty hack, as you're now relying on an external source to load external files which could just as easily be done via include()/require().

Comment: I was trying to replicate the Application.cfm utility from Coldfusion where no matter where you are under the root directory the file would be included and executed without explicitly calling include()/require() on each page.
It might be hack, a nasty one at that too, however until I have a better solution for our current setup, it'll do.
I'm trying to replicate that hack in IIS as well.

Keep in mind that this is for internal purposes and limited to 100-200 users.

Answer (score 1):

You can either [use the registry](http://docs.php.net/configuration.changes#configuration.changes.windows) to set a per-directory configuration. Or [.user.ini](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) files (since php 5.3) :

> Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for .htaccess-style INI files on a per-directory basis. These files are processed only by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI. This functionality obsoletes the PECL htscanner extension. If you are using Apache, use .htaccess files for the same effect.